# Meaning of "set out" and "laid out" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning "set out" and "laid out" in the following sentence:

"The city was abuzz, as all who were invited to the royal feast set out their clothes for the banquet and laid out the gifts for the Emperor."

I know the lexical meanings. However, I am not sure they fit in the given context.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is something odd about the sentence. If I am invited somewhere very grand I might set out my best clothes **before** putting them on. If it is the sort of occasion to which I take a gift then I would lay out the gift **after** I arrive, when the gift is presented.

To put both activites in the same sentence therefore seems strange.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. 

You wrote:

"If I am invited somewhere very grand I might set out my best clothes before putting them on."

Could you please explain the words "set out" in the sentence above?

Comment: I take the clothes from the wardrobe and put them on my bed to make sure that they are clean and properly pressed that no buttons are missing etc. I would call that 'setting out' my clothes.